# MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait doesn't work when updating data

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I use MagicalRecord v2.3.0 beta 3. I see that MR_contextForCurrentThread is deprecated and saveWithBlockAndWait is recommended. So I wrote my code for updating one item like this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
   Item *item = [Item MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
   item.text = newText;
}];
```

But this doesn't work. However, the saveWithBlockAndWait works well with insert and delete.

Then I have to use MR_contextForCurrentThread to make the updating work.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext    = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
Item *item = [Item MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:itemId];
item.text = newText;     
[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How many objects are you saving / updating? How frequently? Have you seen any issues from running your updates on the main thread (keep things simple and refactor when you have actual reason to).

Comment: I test to update only one object in my unit test and it is not frequent because I test it manually. I haven't tested it in my main thread yet.

Comment: The way you've written your first example should work. When you say it doesn't work, what are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: In the first way, the item's text is not changed after the saveWithBlockAndWait is called. That's why I ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, that you want to **update**, but your code is going to *create* a new entity into the current context.

Maybe the correct code could be:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
   Item *item = [Item MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:itemId inContext:localContext];
   item.text = newText;
}];
```

This code should update your entity specified by the itemID.

Good luck!